# R: Parsing language object to get Formula

Tags: r, systemfit

I am trying to parse a `selection` object (returned by the `selection` function in the [sampleSelection](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/sampleSelection/index.html) package), so that it becomes fit for the construction of a `Formula` object (from the [Formula package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Formula/index.html)).

A concrete example of what I want is given below. I have a strategy in mind, but for that strategy to work, I need to understand the R `language` data type a little better.

I am basically looking for an explanation of the R `language` data type/object in the context below.

Here is an example:

```
library(Formula)
library(sampleSelection)
data(Mroz87)
# define a new variable
Mroz87$kids  = (Mroz87$kids5 + Mroz87$kids618 > 0)
# create the estimation sample
Mroz87Est = Mroz87[1:600, ]
# create the hold out sample
Mroz87Holdout = Mroz87[601:nrow(Mroz87), ]
# estimate the model using MLE
heckML =  selection(selection = lfp ~ age + I(age^2) + faminc + kids + educ,
         outcome = wage ~ exper + I(exper^2) + educ + city, data = Mroz87Est) 
summary(heckML)
```

This code estimates a Heckman sample selection model and the model object of class `selection` is available in `heckML`. It has a complicated structure which can be seen by a call to `str(heckML)`.

I need to be able to populate a `Formula` object like this programmatically from the `selection` object `heckML`:

```
FormHeck = Formula(lfp |  wage ~ age + I(age^2) + faminc + kids + educ | 
                     exper + I(exper^2) + educ + city)
```

for downstream processing.

I know that all the components I need to populate this are available in `heckML$call$selection` and `heckML$call$outcome`, and I can use it like so

```
tempS = evalq(heckML$call$selection)
tempO = evalq(heckML$call$outcome)

as.Formula(paste0(tempO[2], '|', tempS[2], '~', tempO[3], '|', tempS[3]))
```

but I have no idea why this works. Note that `tempS` and `tempO` are objects of type `language`.

a. What does `evalq` do with the `language` object? What is it supposed to do?
b. How is a `language` object different from an `expression` object? When to use either?
Pointers to readings welcome.

Lastly, I was wondering if there is a nicer way to populate the `Formula` object `FormHeck` form the return object `heckML`. The above is just one strategy that works, and until I understand why, it is basically a hack.

Thanks.